# density of unipotent flows in algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a reductive algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}$ with a model $G$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $G(\mathbb{R})$ is compact modulo centre. Let $T$ be a maximal torus of $\mathcal{G}$. My question is: whether there exist a prime $p$ and a (non-trivial) homomorphism of $p$-adic groups $\phi_p\colon\mathbb{Q}_p\rightarrow G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ such that the image $\mathrm{Im}(\phi_p)$ is normalized by the maximal torus $T(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and the product set $G(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}])\mathrm{Im}(\phi_p)$ is dense in $G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$?

The question can also be reformulated as follows: whether there exist a prime $p$ and a homomorphism of $p$-adic groups $\phi_p\colon\mathbb{Q}_p\rightarrow G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ such that $\mathrm{Im}(\phi_p)$ is normalized by $T(\mathbb{Q})$(equivalently, by $T(\mathbb{Q}_p)$) and $G(\mathbb{Q})\mathrm{Im}(\phi_p)$ is dense in $G(\mathbb{A}_f)$?

We know that $\mathrm{Im}(\phi_p)$ is contained in a unipotent subgroup of $G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, thus 'unipotent flow' in the title. For the case $G=B^\times$ for some definite quaternion algebra $B$ of centre $\mathbb{Q}$, this answer is affirmative(a special case of Ratner's theorem). If we drop the condition that $\mathrm{Im}(\phi_p)$ being normalized by $T(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, this is also affirmative(using Hedlund's lemma, for example). I am wondering if there are any results related to the above question for general $G$. I feel that we need to put some condition such as  'simply-connected' on $G$, but I do not know how to prove it in this case.